# How to persist a Bean with Collection property in JPA?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

I have the following entity classes:

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Senha")
    private String senha;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Nome")
    private String nome;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usuarioCollection", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Grupo> grupoCollection;      

}
```

and

```
public class Grupo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Nome")
    private String nome;
    @JoinTable(name = "usuario_grupo", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "GrupoID", referencedColumnName = "Id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "UsuarioID", referencedColumnName = "Id")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Usuario> usuarioCollection;

}
```

These codes were generated by netbeans.

When I try to persist it with JPA

```
entityManager.persist(usuario);
```

It executes, but there is no registers in the usuario_grupo table.

ie, the usuario is registered in the table (the grupo already exists in the table grupo), but the usuario_grupo doesn't.

Do you know how I can do this properly?

NOTE: some names are in portuguese.

Comment: Your code is very long. Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I edited the post to hide useless code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

JPA does not like `Collection`. It works with `Set` (unordered collections),  `List` (ordered collections), I believe also with `HashMap` (I have not needed that so I am not sure).

If your bean **must** have the `Collection` attribute, make it `transient` and make a new attibute (the get and set methods, at least) that manages that `Collection` as a `Set` or `List`.

Comment: This answer is not correct, unfortunately. Collection properties are OK, and by the way this is the default choice when you use NetBeans wizard. The OP problem is caused by something else

Comment: Indeed, totally wrong. Maybe the JPA implementation in question has some problem with Collection fields, but then it wouldn't be a compliant implementation if so ... and the OP doesn't mention what is being used.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are not adding the objects to both sides of the collection relationship, so they are not written.